# Выбор пола для регистрации на сайте

Tags: выбор-слов

Перевожу приложение на русский язык.  Пользователи - взрослые, могут быть и подростки.
Пользователя просят зарегистрироваться и при этом выбрать свой пол.
Там нет метки "Пол:" и падающего меню с выбором, а просто 2 кнопки на выбор: Male & Female.
Первое, что приходит в голову, это перевести "Мужчина" и "Женщина". Но мне это как-то непривычно.  Так приемлемо писать в анкете?
Может, лучше "Джентельмен"/"Дама"?
Может, можно еще как-нибудь?

Upd: Плохо объяснила :(
Нет слова "пол"/"гендер"/"секс". 
Есть только кнопки эМ и Жо.
Я не могу назвать их "мужской" и "женский", потому что нет слова "пол".
И я не могу вставить это слово, потому что я перевожу уже существующий дизайн.
То есть получается заполненная форма такая:
- Маша
- Иванова
- миванова@gmail.com
- женский
 (женщина)
[image: Регистрация]

Comment: А разве у нас в анкетах не пишут "пол: мужской / женский"? Это подходит для пользователей любого возраста.

Comment: Пишут. даже "Секс" пишут. И отвечают "Ежедневно". А на М или Ж - "А это мне все равно".

Comment: Да плевать, как выглядит форма. Вы же интерфейс локализуете, а не форму. Сделайте скрин экрана в момент выбора - посмотрим.

Comment: Добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После долгих размышлений я догадалась вставить слово "пол" на сами кнопки:
 *"мужского пола"* и *"женского пола"*.
Веб-дизайнеру также предложена версия на случай, что надписи не влезут на кнопки: *"муж. пола"* и *"жен. пола"*.

Спасибо всем, кто отвечал и комментировал, мне это помогло в генерации идей.

Answer (score 1):

Ставьте по обычаю: муж. - жен. Подростки не обижаются.

Answer (score 0):

Если это что-то типа анкеты для сайта знакомств, то имеет смысл "пол" перевести как "гендер"(опускаю объяснение разницы во избежание обвинений в немодной нынче толерантности к нетрадиционалам), а женщину-мужчину заменить на "парень" и "девушка" или что-то подобное.

Для всех остальных случаев смело пишите "пол", "М" и "Ж". Не перепутают.
(+)
Теперь ясно.
Я бы перевел эти кнопки "Я - мужчина" и "Я  - женщина". Ну или "Я - парень" и "я - девушка", если пол важен по направленности ресурса, а не из вежливости.

Как вариант: "Он" - "Она". Но на русском третье лицо хуже воспринимается.